# Convert jquery ajax post request to fetch api

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, fetch-api

I have convert some jquery code to javascript code. Rest is done. The only part I am struggling with is to convert `$.ajax` to `fetch`. The code original jquery code is

```
$.ajax({
   url: "./assets/php/result.php",
   type: "POST",
   data: {
      name: $("#name").val(),
      token: token,
      email: $("#email").val(),
      subject: $("#subject").val(),
      message: $("#message").val(),
   },
   success: function (data) {
      if (data.indexOf("done") != -1) {
         $("#contact").trigger("reset");
         $("#thanks").fadeOut(100);
         $("#success").fadeIn(1000);
      } else {
         console.log(data);
         $("#success").fadeOut(100);
         $("#thanks").fadeOut(100);
         $("#error").fadeIn(1000);
      }
   },
   error: function (xhr, textStatus, error) {
      console.log(xhr.statusText);
      console.log(textStatus);
      console.log(error);
   },
});
```

Here is my try to convert it into fetch. But the problem is that the response is not getting anything in case of `fetch`

```
const dataToSend = {
   name: name.value,
   token: token,
   email: email.value,
   subject: subject.value,
   message: message.value,
};
console.log(dataToSend);

fetch("./assets/php/result.php", {
   body: JSON.stringify(dataToSend),
   headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
   method: "POST", // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
   mode: "cors", // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
   cache: "no-cache", // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
   credentials: "same-origin", // include, *same-origin, omit
   headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
   },
   redirect: "follow", // manual, *follow, error
   referrerPolicy: "no-referrer", // no-referrer, *no-referrer-when-downgrade, origin, origin-when-cross-origin, same-origin, strict-origin, strict-origin-when-cross-origin, unsafe-url
})
   .then((response) => {
      response.text().then((data) => {
         if (data.indexOf("done") !== -1) {
            qs("#contact").reset();
            fade(qs("#thanks"), "out", 100);
            fade(qs("#success"), "in", 1000);
         } else {
            fade(qs("#success"), "out", 100);
            fade(qs("#thanks"), "out", 100);
            fade(qs("#error"), "in", 1000);
         }
      });
   })
   .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
   });
```

From the php file its just returning two string `'done'` or `no` depending on the data. In php file its using echo like below.

```
echo "no";
```

The `php` files looks as below. Some secret details are changed with "REMOVED" in the code.

```
<?php
require_once('phpMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');

if(isset($_POST['name'])){
$name = $_POST['name'];
$mail = $_POST['email'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$tt = 'REMOVED';

$secret = "REMOVED";
$remoteip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
$url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify";
$response = $_POST["token"];

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
    'secret' => $secret,
    'response' => $response,
    'remoteip' => $remoteip
    ));
$curlData = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
$recaptcha = json_decode($curlData, true);

if ($recaptcha["success"]){


     $mailer = new PHPMailer();

        $mailer->isSMTP();
        $mailer->From = 'REMOVED'; 
        $mailer->FromName = 'Website Contact Form';
        $mailer->Host = 'REMOVED';
        $mailer->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mailer->Username = 'REMOVED'; 
        $mailer->Password = 'REMOVED'; 
        $mailer->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
        $mailer->Port = 465;
        $mailer->addAddress($tt);
        if ($mailer->addReplyTo($mail,$name)) {
            $mailer->isHTML(true);
            $mailer->Body = 
            '
            
                 Contact form submission from  '.$name.' - <a href="mailto:'.$mail.'">'.$mail.'</a><br><br>
                 
                 
                 
                 
                  '.$message.'
            ';
          
            $mailer->Subject = $subject;

            if (!$mailer->send()) {
                echo "Mailer Error: " . $mailer->ErrorInfo;
            } else {
                echo "done";
            }
        }

}
else{
    echo "no";
}
}
?>
```

Kindly see the steps and  tell me if I miss anything essential.

Comment: what the server received?

Comment: @appleapple Mean you wanna see php file?

Comment: php file is good. well, I was asking what the server sees the message.

Comment: @appleapple I have added the php file

Comment: I don't think jQuery send the object as `JSON` here. (just did a quick glance of doc, I'm not familiar with jQuery)

Comment: @appleapple The `ajax` code is working fine but when I replace it with the `fetch` code it doesn't get any response from the the file. Any fix. I don't understand backend well

Comment: @appleapple Am I passing wrong data in case of `fetch`. Should I remove `stringify`?

Comment: I'm not sure, that's why I ask for what the server received (or what actually send out).

Comment: Anyway It should be clear what's different from seeing the raw trasmitted message.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229902/discussion-between-maheer-ali-and-apple-apple).